# Create ID attribute to html tags based on the content of the tag in php

Tags: php, html

my question seems to be simple but I didn't find any information about it..

An ajax request is send to server with content generated by a TinyMCE editor input (basic html).

I want the PHP to create IDs to be accessed by a menu based on `<h1>` to `<h6>` tags.

Sample content :

```
$html = "
<h1>First</h1>
<p>Some content</p>
<h2>Second</h2>
<p>Other content</p>
";
```

Is there an easy way that a proccessing outputs :

```
$html = "
<h1 id='first'>First</h1>
<p>Some content</p>
<h2 id='second'>Second</h2>
<p>Other content</p>
";
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to select any header (`h1,h2...h6`) and then give them an id based on the order in which you found them? Also, is this flat or hierarchical?

Comment: Javascript is the best way of creating id in DOM.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes that's it ! I want the search to be just flat since I don't think editors will nest <h1-6> (I hope so !)

Comment: Maybe  https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery would be useful to you. Haven't used it, but sounds good on paper.

Answer (score 1):

when you init your editor, you can to specify some configuration.

You can to add this :

```
style_formats: [
    {title: 'Title 1', block: 'h1', attributes: {id: 'first'}},
    {title: 'Title 2', block: 'h2', attributes: {id: 'second'}},
```

],

Comment: Thanks for specifying it, even if I could use your technique for other case, I need server-side processing...